# Allow Login from Different Domain having user login details on a single database of one particular domain - Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, session, authentication, joomla1.5

I have a CMS admin created using **Joomla 1.5**. And Client doesn't want to upgrade it. The CMS has a Database having all user details

Joomla 1.5 stores a login session reference in **jos_session** table.

I have 2 domain hosted on different server and I'm accessing Database of 1 domain from other server. I'm able to login from both domain with same user credentials independently.

However ***I cannot concurrently log in both domain using same credentials as jos_session reference gets override***. And as I check the other domain **its auto logs out user**.

Is there anyway to allow concurrent login using same user credential available on single database and some changes that can be done to store user session reference in jos_session ?

Comment: When you have Joomla-specific questions, please post them at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share sessions like that across sites as the session cookie won't match or be created. There are several extensions on JED which allow you to share data (like users) and sessions across sites, you can find them [here](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/)